# How to translate PHP's CURL_COOKIESESSION to VBA?

Tags: php, vba, excel, curl

I'm figuring out how to use the current cookie session (given or will be given by the web service randomly to me) before sending the HTTP request.

Here's how I do it in PHP.

```
$options        = array(
..
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION   => TRUE
..);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

What is the equivalent code to be used when executing this in Excel VBA?

PS: I'm using WinHTTPRequest by the way.

Comment: You want to delete session cookies before sending the HTTP request?

Comment: The web service is requiring referer cookie and current cookie. Referer cookie is easy to get. The next problem is to POST an HTTP and using the (would be provided) cookie as request header before sending the POST request.